# How would I convert a gif to multiple spritesheets?

Tags: c#, gif

I have a gif and I'd like to convert it to multiple spritesheets that have the same size for each frame.

The following code takes my gif and converts it into many png files containing each frame:

```
public static Image[] framesFromGIF(Image IMG)
{
    List<Image> IMGs = new List<Image>();
    int Length = IMG.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Time);

    for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
    {
        IMG.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Time, i);
        IMGs.Add(new Bitmap(IMG));
    }

    return IMGs.ToArray();
}

string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\myGif.gif";
Image gifImg = Image.FromFile(path);
FrameDimension dimension = new FrameDimension(gifImg.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
// Number of frames
int frameCount = gifImg.GetFrameCount(dimension);
ToOutput("Number of Frames: " + frameCount.ToString());
ToOutput("Height: " + gifImg.Height + "px, " + "Width: " + gifImg.Width + "px.");
for (int i = 1; i <= framesFromGIF(gifImg).Length; i++) {
    framesFromGIF(gifImg)[i].Save("F" + i.ToString() + "_myGif.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

This link contains the original gif.
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/435156455272873994/465576709110890497/Bulbasaur.gif

This png is one of the ideal png sheets I'd like to create.
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/435156455272873994/465576801750482944/Bulbasaur-0.png

I want to be able to have multiple of these png sheets while still maintaining the uniform size for all of them. e.g one spritesheet could have 40 frames and one could have 10, while having the same sized frames.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A new image can be created by initializing a [`Bitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) to the desired size. Then you can use [`Graphics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx) to copy the source image to the next position in the combined image.

```
private Image combineFrames(Image[] images, int columns) {
    int rows = (int) Math.Ceiling((double) images.Length / columns);

    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(images[0].Width * columns, images[0].Height * rows) {
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < images.Length; ++i) {
                Image image = images[i];

                graphics.DrawImage(
                    image,
                    image.Width * (i % columns),
                    image.Height * (int) ((double) i / columns)
                ); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to create multiple spritesheets using this. However, I wasn't able to figure out why the last spritesheet, (the one with frames that aren't filled up) wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [System.Windows.Media.Imaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging?view=netframework-4.7.2) [BitmapDecoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapdecoder?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) / [BitmapEncoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder?view=netframework-4.7.2) classes source Frames.

First, a Gif Image file stream is opened and decoded using `BitmapDecoder.Create(SourceStream)`, then each frame is passed to a [PngBitmapEncoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.pngbitmapencoder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and saved as PNG image.

A progressive number is added to each frame file.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

int CurrentFrame = 0;
string SourceFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "myGif.gif");
string FramesDestinationPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "myGif-Frames");

using (FileStream SourceStream = new FileStream(SourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
{
    var bitmapDecoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(SourceStream,
                        BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
                        BitmapCacheOption.Default);
    foreach (BitmapFrame frame in bitmapDecoder.Frames)
    {
        ++CurrentFrame;
        using (FileStream PngStream = new FileStream(FramesDestinationPath + $@"\frame{CurrentFrame}.png", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            PngBitmapEncoder PngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            PngEncoder.Frames.Add(frame);
            PngEncoder.Save(PngStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Note:
*You need to create the* `myGif-Frames` *folder on your Desktop beforehand, or add a line of code that creates it where you want it to be.*